# ListView replaces first object instead of adding a new one

Tags: android, listview

I created a test project, and in that project I am trying to create a listview that the user can add to when they click a button. The button opens an new activity with an editText and another button to go back to the listview activity and an item should have been added. It works the first time, but when I add another Item it replaces the old one. I have search for a while now, and all the other answer don't seem to help me. Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView simpleList;
String input;
ArrayList<Item> listItems =new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    simpleList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    addData();
    MyAdapter myAdapter=new MyAdapter(this,R.layout.row, listItems);
    simpleList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
}

public void addData(){
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        input = extras.getString("Homework");
        listItems.add(new Item(input, input, input));
    }
}

public void toInput(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, inputScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}}
```

This is my main activity, the adapter is a custom adapter that is made in this class.

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Item> {
ArrayList<Item> listItems = new ArrayList<>();

public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<Item> objects){
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    listItems = objects;
}

public int getCount(){
    return super.getCount();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View v = convertView;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.homeworkDisplay);
    TextView textView2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dueDisplay);
    TextView textView3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.classDisplay);
    textView.setText(listItems.get(position).getHomework());
    textView2.setText(listItems.get(position).getDate());
    textView3.setText(listItems.get(position).getClasses());
    return v;
}}
```

The string that is added to the listview is sent from the another activity that gets it from an editText, here is it's class

```
public class inputScreen extends Activity{

EditText userInput;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.input_screen);
    userInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);


}

public void sendInfo(View view){
    Intent goingBack = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    goingBack.putExtra("Homework", userInput.getText().toString());
    startActivity(goingBack);

}}
```

I know there is alot of code there, you don't need to go through it all as I am sure the problem is in MainActivity. I have another class called items that returns homework. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used startActivity() is not correct.
your activity stack is like this :

the start
~~~~~~~~~~~~
MainActivity
~~~~~~~~~~~~

after you call toInput in MainActivity()

~~~~~~~~~~~~
InputScreen(activity)
MainActivity
~~~~~~~~~~~~

then when you call send() in InputScreen

~~~~~~~~~~~~
MainActivity
InputScreen
MainActivity
~~~~~~~~~~~~

see what's happening?

the first time in InputScreen you called send() start MainActivity with extras

then you started a new MainActivity ,then went the addData() ,you got data, and changed listView.

but when you do it again , you always start new Activities ,so only the first one was gonna change

always repeat the first step always start a new activity

you should call startActivityForResult() in MainActivity to start inputScreen and override the onActivityResult method in MainActivity

just google startActivity and startActivityForResult you will work this out .
and anther key word you should google is ,listView --> data source

sorry,I am not a native English speaker, if I did something wrong ,please forgive me ~~~~

Comment: Thanks dude, I'll check this out and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Written by: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2936153/rohit5k2

Source: **[Listview replaces first item instead of creating new items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28205853/listview-replaces-first-item-instead-of-creating-new-items?rq=1)**

> Every time you call `changeText()` your adapter is reset so only one
>   item will be displayed
>
> Change your fragment like this
>
> ```
> public class ListViewFragment1 extends Fragment {
>
> protected ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
> ListView list1;
>
> @Override
> public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
>         @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_fragment1, container, false);       
>     adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.items);
>     list1 = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview1);
>     list1.setAdapter(adapter1);
>     return view;
> }
>
> public void changeText(String data){
>     adapter1.add(data);
>     adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
> }
> }
> ```

Comment: This doesn't help me, I had already read this and I still don't know what to do.

Comment: This might take a while.

Comment: Thanks dude! You can take as much time as u need.

Comment: Hey I figured it out so don't worry about the code.